# How to correctly normalize modulus and phase of an eigenvector?

Tags: finite-element, eigensystem, eigenvalues

I am solving a linear stability problem using finite element discretization. Then, I have a generalised eigenvalue problem:
$$ \lambda M x = J x.$$
I obtain complex eigenvalue and eigenvectors from Arpack using inverse shift method. I would like to compare the eigenvectors obtained with different meshes. To do this it is necessary to normalize norm and phase in a proper way. As concerns the norm of the eigenvector I normalize it imposing: 
$$ x^HMx = 1. $$
Now, I would need an integral norm for the phase too. I tried one but it doesn't seem to work. I cannot obtain similar eigenvectors with two different meshes.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by "compare eigenvectors"? If you just want to measure a concept of distance between them, I would use the [angle](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subspace.html) between subspaces, which is independent of the normalization.

Comment: I want to visualize the velocity field containted in the eigenvectors with Paraview. I would expect to see something similar or the same thing if the two eigenvectors are correctly normalized. Am I wrong?

Comment: What kind of velocities do you have that have a complex phase?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to some work of Peter Arbenz: 
http://people.inf.ethz.ch/arbenz/publications.html

He had worked out some generalized eigenvalue problems with constraint condition (I remembered that he used the Jacobi–Davidson Algorithm), his model problems came from the FEM for Maxwell equations.

Comment: There are 109 references in your link. Would you mind adding a summary of what you want to highlight from there?